# Image in flex box column in chrome v88

Tags: google-chrome

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <img src="https://gimg2.baidu.com/image_search/src=http%3A%2F%2Fimg5.hao123.com%2Fdata%2Fdesktop%2Fc6e5f6e1d724814608285c8c6c7ebffc_1366_768&refer=http%3A%2F%2Fimg5.hao123.com&app=2002&size=f9999,10000&q=a80&n=0&g=0n&fmt=jpeg?sec=1614411062&t=0fe9a27fb2e008faf5f3f062ca4b98af" alt="">
    <span>wihwiwndsjndsjdn</span>
</div>
```

when i update chrome to version88, the image display its raw size. is chrome update something?